# How to add a Python string variable to part of a SQL string variable in Python?

Tags: python, r, sqlalchemy, pycharm, amazon-redshift

I am working in Python with SQLAlchemy to execute Redshift SQL queries.  I am defining the SQL I want to execute as python strings  I want to create some additional python string variables that will become a section of the SQL strings. For instance, in the below example, the table name in the SQL query can be built from the python variable "table_string" plus the rest of the table name itself. In this example the resulting table name would be "test_table_name".

```
table_string = 'test_'

create_test_sql_string_python='''
begin;
create table 'table_string'+'table_name'
(id int not null, name varchar(40), date timestamp);
end;
'''
execute(sa.text(create_test_sql_string_python).execution_options(autocommit=True))
```

I have done something similar in R and am wondering what the python equivalent of this may be. Here is the R sample:

```
table_string <- 'test_'
dbSendQuery(redshift,paste0("begin;
                         create table ",table_string,"table_name
                         (id int not null, name varchar(40), date timestamp);
                          end;"))
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `.format` method can be used (see [PyFormat Documentation](https://pyformat.info/)). In you case, it would look like that:

```
table_string = 'test_'

create_test_sql_string_python='''
begin;
create table {0}table_name
(id int not null, name varchar(40), date timestamp);
end;
'''.format(table_string)
```

Placing `{0}` inside the string will substitute there the first argument inside `.format()`, which could have more than one argument.

Comment: I think `"table_name"` is a typo tbh. Upvote though; you beat me to it (though we have different documentation) :)

Comment: From the R code example and the question saying that the resulting table name should be "test_table_name" I understood that the variable table_string was just a prefix

Comment: Sorry, I meant a typo on the OP's behalf. But for redshift, specifically, I can't be sure. I'd be surprised if you had to have `"table_name"` to qualify what you were specifying but I may be wrong.

Comment: Thanks both of you.  This works.  I have a situation where I need to end up using several different variable stings inside SQL variable strings.  Trying to avoid having to modify any of the actual SQL and just have a list of variables to change once at the top of the python file before running the entire thing. Haven't got that far yet but this will definitely help out.

Answer (score 2):

I can't comment on the SQL statement itself, but you can use [`format`](https://docs.python.org/3.4/library/functions.html#format) to pass a variable here.

The string would look like:

```
"""
begin;
create table {} (id int not null, 
                 name varchar(40), 
                 date timestamp);
end;
""".format(table_string)
```